# Most secure way to submit form automatically after X minutes? (for online exam)

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

*(I am not good at English)*

We are developing an online exam tool. Users will have to answer a few question, and have X minutes for do that. After the X minutes, the form has to be send automatically, saving the questions answered until that time.

I think doing a countdown in Javascript would be okay, but an student with knowledge for use the Firefox console could avoid it, and have unlimited time.

I thought in saving a cookie with the moment the exam was opened. If the form is submitted after that (I would check it on the server side), I could make it as invalid, but I'd lost any valid answers (I mean, answers written before the X minutes).

What do you think? Is there a good practice for this?

Comment: 1. Store the time of exam start on server 2. Cookies are easy to forge as well 3. Split a form to multiple steps and save the answer after every step

Comment: You could push every single action (so when someone selects an answer, it is sent at that moment)

Comment: Yes, I could do that using ajax, that's true. **Thank you, guys!**

Comment: @zerkms: Definitely, regard the exam as having not submitted if not submitted to the server in time - no client stuff should be controlling that!